# Display UTF-8 characters in VB 6.0

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, com, vb6

My application is a layered application in which layer 1 gets data from layer 0 via a API call, during such a call it gets data from layer-0 as char*, Layer -1 converts this to BSTR and sends it to application.
The layer-0 is sending the data in the UTF-8 format.( Russian characters)

At the application the data received from layer-1 is not displayed correctly.

I intercepted the data from layer-1 and copied into Nodepad++ and then using the “Encoding” option , I choose the “Encode in UTF-8” and I got the data back.

My application should be able to do the same thing that NotePad++ is able to do, just encode to UTF-8

The application is VB 6.0.

Thank you looking into this, your suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: VB6 isn't any different from most programming tools and COM servers and your operating system.  Strings are always encoded in utf-16.  Any bytes that encode a string in utf-8 must be converted to a utf-16 string before it is assigned to a BSTR.  With for example MultiByteToWideString().  Recovering a badly encoded string is not generally possible, the utf-8 byte values might match a utf-16 surrogate.

Comment: What is the `BSTR` actually being used for? "*At the application the data received from layer-1 is not displayed correctly*" - how is it being converted from UTF-8 to `BSTR` exactly, and how is it being displayed exactly? If the `BSTR` is just being used for transport purposes, it is possible to store 8bit binary data in a `BSTR` using [`SysAllocStringByteLen()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221637.aspx). Or, you could use a `SAFEARRAY` instead. Either way, you could pass the UTF-8 as-is to the application and let it handle UTF-8 processing as needed.

Comment: Otherwise, if the `BSTR` should be treated as actual text, then yes, do convert the UTF-8 to UTF-16 first using [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072.aspx), and then from UTF-16 to `BSTR` using [`SysAllocString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221458.aspx) or [`SysAllocStringLen()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221639.aspx).

Comment: Many Many Thanks Hans ..it worked also Thank you Remy